# Generate system hashs with BIOS

Tags: bios, tpm

Is it possible to generate system hashes of installed hardware (CPU, Video controller etc.) with the BIOS and then store them in a TPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. TPM and UEFI can establish a root of trust to ensure platform integrity.

But the responsibility to check for and ascertain this integrity is with the operating system.

Comment: I don't have to verify it there, just store it; do you have a good rerence/documentation for this?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/shpedoikal/tpm-luks. But if you wait till I reach home during the weekend, I can cite my Microsoft books that I used to get certified as my reference.